# how to get size of WriteableBitmap in C# Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I wanted to get the size of System.Windows.Media.Imaging WriteableBitmap in Silverlight. Any suggestions will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Size in pixels? Device-independent units? Bytes?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx

For dimensions in pixels, try the PixelWidth and PixelHeight properties. For dimensions in device-independent units, try the Width and Height properties.